# How to add tab before table?

Tags: perl, whitespace

I want to have this output
[tab space before TabularDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0GIz.png)

I am trying to print tab space in front of the whole table. I tried adding tab space before : print $table->render;
but it's adding tab space before the first line only. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to modify the string returned by `$table->render`...

```c
print $table->render =~ s/^/\t/mgr;
```